# How to combine Browserify and Google Closure with type checks

Tags: javascript, google-closure-compiler, browserify

When Browserify combines my JavaScript-files, the result looks something like this:

```
(function e(t,n,r){function s(o,u){if(!n[o]){if(!t[o]){var a=typeof require=="function"&&require;if(!u&&a)return a(o,!0);if(i)return i(o,!0);throw new Error("Cannot find module '"+o+"'")}var f=n[o]={exports:{}};t[o][0].call(f.exports,function(e){var n=t[o][1][e];return s(n?n:e)},f,f.exports,e,t,n,r)}return n[o].exports}var i=typeof require=="function"&&require;for(var o=0;o<r.length;o++)s(r[o]);return s})({1:[function(require,module,exports){
    // Including file contents
},{"foo":3}],3:[function(require,module,exports){
    // Included file contents

...
```

The Google Closure Compile with type checks (--jscomp_warning=checkTypes) complains about the function `s` which get called with one parameter instead of the required two.

I'm currently replacing the definition of `s`

```
function s(o,u){
```

with

```
/** @param {*=} o @param {*=} u */function s(o,u){
```

as a preprocessing-step.

There must, however, be a nicer way. My question is: how to combine Browserify with Google Closure Compiler with type checks on **without** find-and-replacing the definition of `s`?

Comment: Why type check after browserify?

Comment: I'd like to add a little bit more type-safety to JavaScript. Annotating my functions so that the Closure Compilers checks that what is passed into these functions is correct is something I am primarely interested in. Are there maybe alternatives?

Comment: Basically, I think you want to check the code before running browserify